# how to set width of each 'LI' element to its 'content size' in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using mdbootstrap3 tab.
I want set each li width to its content. for example I have three li.

first li content) Practice Timing
second li content) Categories
third li content) Default Setting

I try this code get all li width

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-4 cal-tab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#parc-time"><span>Practice Timing</span></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="cate">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="defa-sett">Default Setting</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
var totalWidth = 0;
$(".cal-tab li").each(function() { totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); });
```

Thankes in advance

Comment: Please provide a runnable code,and explain properly..its bit difficult to understand your requirwement.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the width to? The `li` or the `ul`? At the moment you are storing all of the `li` widths in a variable and you don't do anything with that variable.

Comment: I am trying to set li width in ul. Related to its content.

Comment: Why you need width on list items? Can you shown us an image what you are trying to achieve? Please share us your css as well..

Comment: @Mohammad Usman
Because of my client need to set li bottom border to width of content. not set border bottom to width of li.
i use the material bootstrap 3 so no need to write to css